# query to check whether IP address falls in range of the startIP and EndIp columns in the table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, node-postgres

I need to stop some IP addresses from accessing my app. I need to write a query using postgres to check whether an IP(coming dynamically) falls in any range between startip and endip stored in the db.

```
    Arr.forEach((element,index)=>{
    client.query("select exists(select 1 from data where ip_start=$1 OR ip_end = $2 between ip_start and ip_end)", 
    [Arr[index].ip,Arr[index].ip])
   .then((res =>{console.log(res)
   }
  ))
 })
```

Comment: `client.query("select exists(select 1 from data where $1 between ip_start and ip_end)"`

Comment: What data type are the columns `ip_start` and `ip_end`

Comment: Use the correct [data type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-net-types.html) for `ip_start` and `ip_end` (and your incoming data, using a cast) and it should Just Work.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the datatype is inet